# MFC: Handling character events in frame or application

Tags: c++, mfc

Say I have a large application frame in which I want default input to be a particular, central widget in that frame.  If a key, like delete or escape, is pressed:

- within a control that listens to that key I want that control to handle it.
- within a control that does not care about that key, I want it passed to the central widget.

In WX I was able to do this with the escape key by overriding ProcessEvent within the application.  I then told the application base to try dealing with it (which would send the event to the control for attempted processing) and if it didn't I would send it to the right widget.

I can't seem to find a correlary within MFC.  It seems that character events never get sent up the window tree to the parents or to the application.  What can I do?

Comment: There is no answer to this question.  It can't be done.  PreTranslate is too early and there's no other option.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to intercept all [`WM_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28VS.85%29.aspx) messages by overriding [`CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cw1sb70c%28VS.80%29.aspx) in your CWinApp derived class.

Example:

```
BOOL CMyApp::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if ( pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN ) {
        // Do something special with this message
    }

    return CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't let the widget with focus attempt to deal with it before I filter it out though does it?